# How to git stage an one by one the folder with files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit, git-add

I have a folder with other subfolders. Then in each subfolder many files (over 1000). I want to stage, commit each subfolder at a time (not all subfolders folders at once).

Do I have in VSCode a way to do this easly form interface? Because I do not want to add 1000 files one by one to click the + sign.

Comment: I think vscode do not have such a feature. Why do you want to use vscode and no git shell like [tortoise git](https://tortoisegit.org/)? If you enlarge the source control view you see the file path of each file. Then you could use `Shift` and `ArrowDown` to select multiple files quite quick.

Comment: I think would be very useful to have this in vscode, why shall I use other tool to work with git? I know that this feature is in Netbeans IDE and was very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this through the integrated terminal. You can choose to add and commit one directory at a time.

```
git status */
```

will show you unstaged/modified directories

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        img/test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

From here you can stage your directories one at a time. This is a simple and quick way. Now you just commit every time after staging a directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try lazygit: https://github.com/jesseduffield/lazygit. It can stage folders one by one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32832900)